# What are the conditions for $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (f_1(x) - f_2(x)) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \lim f_1=0 \land \lim f_2=0$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Given the two functions $f_1(x)=e^{\lambda_1 x},f_2(x) = e^{\lambda_2 x}$ with $\lambda_1,\lambda_2 \in \mathbb C$, When can we say that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (f_1(x) - f_2(x)) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow  (\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f_1(x) = 0 \land \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f_2(x) = 0) $$

Thank you

Comment: use "\lim" to write $\lim$ instead of $lim$

Answer (score 2):

I find the question a bit weird, but I'll leave that to one side.

Since $f_1(x)=e^{\lambda_1 x}$ for some $\lambda_1,\lambda_2 \in \mathbb C,$ then $f_1(x)=0$ is impossible, and so $(\Longleftarrow)$ is always [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) under *any* meaningful conditions.

However, $(\Longrightarrow)$ is always impossible (since $f_1(x)=0$ is always impossible), and therefore there are *no* conditions under which

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (f_1(x) - f_2(x)) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow  (f_1(x) = 0 \land f_2(x) = 0). $$